# Vue component doesn´t rerender after vuex state change

Tags: vue.js, vuex

My vue component doesn´t change a child component when the state of vuex changes.

I have a list of slots for items and want to render items depending on a vuex state variable.

When you click on a "item"-component it sets the `selectedItem` state variable. Another component watches this variable and sets `equippedItems` variable with new data.

But when I try to change an item it doesn't show up, even though the state seems to change in Vuex.

I have set up the vuex store like that:

```js
const state = {
    equippedItems:
        [
            {
                name: 'Item 1',
                strength: 3,
                itemType: 1,
                rarity: 3
            },
            {
                name: 'Item 2',
                strength: 40,
                itemType: 2,
                rarity: 2
            }
        ],
    selectedItem: null
}

const getters = {

    getEquippedItems: (state) => state.equippedItems,


    getSelectedItem: (state) => state.selectedItem
}

const mutations = {

    changeSelectedItem: (state, newItem) => {
        state.selectedItem = newItem;
    },

    changeEquippedItems: (state, parameters) => {
        state.equippedItems[parameters[0]] = parameters[1];
    }
}

const actions = {
    setSelectedItem({ commit }, index) {
        commit('changeSelectedItem', index);
    },

    setNewEquipment({ commit }, parameters) {
        commit('changeEquippedItems', parameters);
    }
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

Then I have a component that sets the items according to the `equippedItems` variable

```js
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';
import Item from '../Item';

export default {
    name: 'equipped-items',
    components: {
        Item
    },
    props: [],
    data() {
        return {
            chooseHead: false,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['getEquippedItems', 'getItems', 'getSelectedItem'])

    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['setNewEquipment']),
        chooseNewHead() {
            this.chooseHead = !this.chooseHead;
        }
    },
    watch: {
        getSelectedItem: function () {
            if (this.chooseHead) {
                this.setNewEquipment([0, this.getSelectedItem]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="equipped-items">

    <div @click="chooseNewHead" class="head equipSlot">
        <Item v-if="getEquippedItems[0]" :passedItem="getEquippedItems[0]" :parent="'equip'"> </Item>
    </div>

    <div class="body equipSlot">
        <Item v-if="getEquippedItems[1]" :passedItem="getEquippedItems[1]"></Item>
    </div>
</section>
```

Then there is the item component which sets the vuex variable `selectedItem` on click.

```js
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
    name: 'Item',
    props: ['passedItem', 'parent'],
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['setSelectedItem']),
        selectedItem() {
            if (this.parent != 'equip') {
                this.setSelectedItem(this.passedItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It renders fine the first time when the page is loading, but doesn't change the new passed item to the item-component.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't see how the click is meant to change things - it looks like it only calls `chooseNewHead` which just toggles the state of `chooseHead` ?

Comment: In the "item" component is the function "selectedItem" which sets the vuex variable "selectedItem". 
In my other component it watches for changes on these variable and changes the equippedItems variable accordingly

Answer (score 1):

There a couple mistakes in your code:

1- I couldn't identify where you call/trigger an event to your `selectedItem()` method in your component.

2-(This is an extra) If you want to append objects to an array injavascript you just use `array.push(odject)`, so i would suggest you to change your `changeEquippedItems` mutation to:

```
changeEquippedItems: (state, parameters) => {
        state.equippedItems.push(parameters);
    }
```

Comment: The event is triggered in the html section of the item component.

And i don´t try to push new items in the array. i want to change them. The first element represents the first item, the second the second item and so on